# Divide second row with first row value in the same column

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a table with column Account.
Return 2 value :
4
2
I tried to divide 2/4 using expression
=Fields!Accounts.Value/Previous(Fields!Accounts.Value)
Something is not work here. Please point out what was wrong with it. Many thanks

Comment: I think it works. But it gave an error cell. I think 2/4 and 4/0 (error )

How do I get rid of the error, just divide 2/4 only
Many thanks

Comment: Dividing by 0 will always produce an error because you can't divide by 0.  The expression should work so long as the value isn't 0.  Add `IsNothing(Previous(Fields!Accounts.Value), 1)` and it should work if there is no previous value and the previous value isn't 0.